# Toggle between Login and Logout React component

Tags: reactjs

I want to toggle on login to logout.

I have implemented it in a way shown below. But it renders only when I refresh the page. I would like that to happen on trigger instead of a hard refresh.

```
import React from "react"; import logo from "../logo.svg"; 
import { isLogin, logout } from '../utils/utility'; 
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; 
import useForceUpdate from 'use-force-update';

const Header = () => {
    let history = useHistory();
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
    return (
        <div>
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <h1 className="App-title">Mobile Store Management System</h1>
                <div>
                    { //Check if message failed
                        
                        isLogin()
                            ? <div> <h4 style={{ display: "inline" }}><button style={{ 'cursor': 'pointer', display: "inline" }}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                logout();
                                forceUpdate();
                                history.push('/')                                
                                
                            }
                            }>Logout</button></h4> </div>
                            : <div> <h4 style={{ display: "inline" }}>
                            <button style={{ 'cursor': 'pointer', display: "inline" }}  
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                logout();
                                forceUpdate() ;
                                history.push('/');
                                
                            }}>Login</button></h4> </div>
                            }
                    
                    <h4 style={{ display: "inline" }}><button style={{ 'cursor': 'pointer', display: "inline" }} onClick={() => history.push('/register')} >Register</button></h4>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    ) } export default Header;
```

Also I have a AppRouter from which it gets generated:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../components/App';
import SignIn from '../components/SignIn'
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';
import PrivateRoute from '../components/PrivateRoutes';
import PublicRoute from '../components/PublicRoute';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Register from '../components/Register'
const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <PublicRoute component={Register} path="/register" exact />
                <PublicRoute restricted={true} component={SignIn} path="/" exact />
                <PrivateRoute component={App} path="/Admin" exact />
                <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
export default AppRouter;
```

Any help would be great thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think anything is causing a re-render as there's nothing changing from React's point of view (at least from the code you've shared). Maybe try controlling the button state with component state and update that on click instead of an imported function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your `isLogin` to a `const`, before rendering page. E.g.

```
import React from "react"; import logo from "../logo.svg"; 
import { isLogin, logout } from '../utils/utility'; 
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; 
import useForceUpdate from 'use-force-update';

const Header = () => {
    let history = useHistory();
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
    const login = isLogin();

    return (
        <div>
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <h1 className="App-title">Mobile Store Management System</h1>
                <div>
                    { // Check if message failed
                        login 
                        ? <div>
                              <h4 style={{ display: "inline" }}>
                                  <button
                                      style={{ 'cursor': 'pointer', display: "inline"}}
                                      onClick={(e) => {
                                          logout();
                                          forceUpdate();
                                          history.push('/')                                
                                      }}
                                  >Logout</button>
                              </h4>
                          </div>
                        : <div>
                              <h4 style={{ display: "inline" }}>
                                  <button
                                      style={{ 'cursor': 'pointer', display: "inline" }}  
                                      onClick={(e) => {
                                          logout();
                                          forceUpdate() ;
                                          history.push('/');
                                      }}
                                  >Login</button>
                              </h4>
                          </div>
                      }
                      <h4 style={{ display: "inline" }}>
                          <button
                              style={{ 'cursor': 'pointer', display: "inline" }}
                              onClick={() => history.push('/register')}
                          >Register</button>
                      </h4>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```